A cover image with a shaded logo on the background of the left and a text on the right. The text also have a logo in there. How to balance the text?
I have this design:

I'm using EB Garamond font with the WordPress logo to display the text. To translate it to English:

Should individuals and small organizations use WordPress?

The yellow phrase means "individuals and small organizations", emphasizing the target reader of the article. I don't translate it in the file because unlike English grammar, in Vietnamese grammar there should be a text after the word WordPress. I think that may affect the composition or something.
My feeling is that the text doesn't seem to be balanced, even though I have aligned them well. Perhaps the background and the logo is overwhelming, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Here are my reasonings:

If I make the text larger then the logo of the background cannot be appreciated. Or should I not care about that, and just use a different background?
I try to make the yellow phrase bigger, but as the white text also necessary to read to get the full sentence, I think they should have the same size.
What colors I should use? Consulting the design library, it seems that only the lemon color #FFF972 is best to be used as highlight color with this background.
Should the logo in the text smaller? I'm not sure if I make it smaller the readers will have enough impressed
What font should I use? Part of me thinks that I get that I don't have to follow the design library, and part of me thinks that I will gain more consistent with the logo if I use it

Resource: SVG file, WordPress design library

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Exact centre alignment doesn't always work. Consider manually moving the longer line with the Word press logo manually, until it looks balanced.  It's off-balance because of the size of the logo.  The rest of your question is too opinion based to be honest.  Font choice, size and colours are highly subjective. There is no correct answer for these.

do you mean that all questions asking for font choice, size and colours are subjective? Also, in my understanding good subjective are allowed. So why are my questions bad subjective?

Yes, as far a layout questions are concerned, nearly all those concerning font choice, size choice and colour choice are just a bit too subjective.  It's not "bad subjective". The problem is what one person likes, another might not, and therefore there can be no single correct answer.  There are many ways to solve such problems. What I would suggest is that you trust your own judgement. Try a few variations. Find something you like, and go with that. It might help your question if you show some variations you have tried rather that asking others to choose for you.

My personal subjective opinion:

don't put a logo in the middle of a sentence: sometimes that can work, but in this case it looks confusing, so just type the name "WordPress"

left align the entire text box, font size up, leading down

colors & fonts are up to you, and generally what you have is ok


